# HTML - Escaping single quotes in form controls

Tags: html

I have a textbox whose value contains a string with a single quote, e.g., *"Andy's String"*:

`<input type='text' value='Andy's String' />`

This obviously does not render correctly in a browser. What's the best way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<input type='text' value='Andy&#39;s String' />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type='text' value="Andy's String" />
```

Alternatively:

```
<input type='text' value='Andy&apos;s String' />
```

Comment: I cant seem to get this escape sequence to work in Internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use double quotes :)

```
<input type="text" value="Andy's String" />
```

Comment: Surely then the same problem would occur with Andy"s string

Comment: It would, but in english people don't write Andy"s, they write Andy's. Although both method has floors, I think this is the best approach (with a bit of validation sprinkled on top ;))

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes '' instead of single.

Comment: Surely then the same problem would occur with Andy"s string